# Complexity of f(k) when f(n) = O(n!) and k=n*(n-1)

Tags: algorithm, function, complexity-theory, factorial

I have the following problem. Let's suppose we have function `f(n)`. Complexity of `f(n)` is `O(n!)`. However, there is also parameter `k=n*(n-1)`. My question is - what is the complexity of `f(k)`? Is it `f(k)=O(k!/k^2)` or something like that, taking into consideration that there is a quadratic relation between `k` and `n`?

Comment: If the complexity of f(n) is O(n!), then the complexity of f(k) is O(k!) by simple name change. It doesn't matter what the relation between n and k is. The relation only matters if you want to represent the complexity of f(k) in terms of n.

Comment: Note that `O(n!)` is usually approximated using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computational complexity is interpreted base on the size of the input. Hence, if `f(n) = O(n!)` when your input is `n`, then `f(k) = O(k!)` when your input is `k`.

Therefore, you don't need to compute the complexity for each value of input for the function `f(n)`. For example, `f(2) = O(2!)`, you don't need to compute the complexity of `f(10)` likes `O((5*2)!)` as `10 = 5 * 2`, and try to simplify it base on the value of `2!`. We can say `f(10) = O(10!)`.

Anyhow, if you want compute `(n*(n-1))! = (n^2 - n)!(n^2 - n + 1)...(n^2 - n + n) /(n^2 - n + 1)...(n^2 - n + n) = (n^2)!/\theta(n^3) = O((n^2)!/n^(2.9))`

Comment: Ok, I see I might have not been clear. My concern is how to represent complexity of f(n) in terms of k. I am not talking about just switching input from n to k.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider that there is a *m*, such that the *n* you used in your f(n) is equal to *m * (m - 1)*.

Does that change the complexity?

---

The *n* in f(n) = O(n!) represents all the valid inputs.

You are trying to pass a variable *k* whose actual value in terms of another variable is *n * (n - 1)*. That does not change the complexity. It will be O(k!) only.